# C# .NET 6 Cambiar lenguaje segun usuario

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hola tengo una aplicacion y me gustaria que cada usuario pudiera seleccionar su idioma.

Tengo 2 archivos resx uno con español y otro con ingles

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que no se si es correcto cambiar el culture de la aplicación, actualmente estoy intentando algo como esto (y funciona):

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = null;
            if (Usuario == "Usuario1")
            {
                cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
            }
            else {
                cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            }

            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

No se si exista otra forma de hacer esto o lo que estoy haciendo es correcto

---

Para agregar una cookie para cambiar el lenguaje hago esto pero no la agrega

```
public IActionResult Login()
{

    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
       CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))),
        new CookieOptions
        {
            Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1),
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
        });

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Te refieres a un programa de escritorio o una página web? La etiqueta de ASP.NET sugiere lo segundo, pero estaría bien que lo aclares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PUedes usar el método `UseRequestLocalization` de la clase `WebApplication` en el Program.cs. Este middleware añade información sobre la ubicación para cada petición, con lo que usará las string del resx automáticamente según lo desee el usuario; de primeras la cabecera `Accept-Language` que envíe su navegador.

[Documentación pertinente](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.applicationbuilderextensions.userequestlocalization?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-builder-applicationbuilderextensions-userequestlocalization(microsoft-aspnetcore-builder-iapplicationbuilder-system-action((microsoft-aspnetcore-builder-requestlocalizationoptions))))

```csharp
/**
...
*/
builder.Services.AddRequestLocalization(
    var supportedCultures = new[] { "es-ES", "en-GB" };
    options.SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
        .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

En [este artículo de Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/select-language-culture?view=aspnetcore-7.0) hablan más sobre las formas de configurar el origen del idioma, ya que puede ser desde la cabecera que mencioné previamente; o desde una cookie (que el usuario puede configurar) o parámetros en la URL (útil para crear enlaces a la página en un idioma concreto).

Comment: Hola muchas gracias logre que funcionara pasandolo como parametro en la url, pero quiero que se haga por cookie pero no puedo agregar una cookie ya segui unos ejemplos y no me deja no se si me puedas ayudar (actualizo pregunta)

Comment: @JorgeLuis ¿Añadiste la opción de cookie al AddRequestLocalization? Me ha funcionando correctamente. Edito la respuesta.

Comment: Hola Ariel lo que no me funciona es HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append ya puse tu codigo y sigue sin funcionar no agrega la cookie :(

Comment: @JorgeLuis ¿En qué entorno estás? ¿Tienes los certificados HTTPS y todo eso bien configurado? ¿Comprobaste que el método se está ejecutando? Prueba a añadirle un Console.WriteLine por si acaso, y cambia el `new RequestCulture` pasándole directamente la cadena "en-US" en vez de instanciar una CultureInfo nueva. Lo siguiente ya es irte a las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador, pestaña Red y mirar las cabeceras de respuesta de la página.